# Character encoding error for .php file

Tags: php, html, json, slim

Have made a route for MarkersController.php which returns json, but when i navigate to the route I get the following error:

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

My route is as follows:

```
$app->get('/markers/?', function () use ($app) {
    $controller = new UF\MarkersController($app);
    return $controller->getMarkersJSON();
});
```

MarkersController.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    {% include 'components/head.html' %}
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
include('DB_INFO.php');

function getMarkersJSON(){     
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server.
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());}
// Sets the active MySQL database.
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());}

// Selects all the rows in the markers table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM tester WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: '. mysqli_error());
}
$markers = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Assuming "lat" is column name in tester table. Please change it if required.
    $lat= $rows['lat'];
    //Assuming "lng" is column name in tester table. Please change it if required.
    $lng= $rows['lng'];
    $markers = array('lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng);
}
echo json_encode($markers);
}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which web browser is telling you this?

Comment: with this code, you output HTML with JSON inside. is this what you realy want ? you don't want JSON that would be read by another program ?

Comment: @mmm No, just want it to output json, that will be used elsewhere...

Comment: @fst104 so get rid of the HTML...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  Still get the error with the html removed!

Comment: You should not have **any** HTML/Twig in your `MarkersController.php`, or any other controller for that matter.  All HTML belongs in your template files: http://www.userfrosting.com/navigating/#twig

Comment: What is the content of `components/head.html`? Can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Content-Type definition into your head.html?
If the answer is no, try to put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=[your-charset]" />
```

into your head.html