# setting response header in Slim/Userfrosting

Tags: php, json, slim

Have a php file that is looking to return json, but continually getting html character encoding error... and no output when i navigate to the route.

MarkersController.php (getMarkersJSON())

```
$markers = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Assuming "lat" is column name in tester table. Please change it if required.
    $lat= $rows['lat'];
    //Assuming "lng" is column name in tester table. Please change it if required.
    $lng= $rows['lng'];

    $markers = array('lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng);
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
echo json_encode($markers);

}
```

Route in index.php

```
$app->get('/markers/', function () use ($app) {
    $controller = new UF\MarkersController($app);
    return $controller->getMarkersJSON();
```

Comment: Since it is a encoding error could you try to place `Content-Type` of `application/json;charset=utf-8`

Comment: Or try to get UTF8 chars from db: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character encoding error for .php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207755/character-encoding-error-for-php-file)